# How to fix “Permission denied to access property 'document'”?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, c#

I posted it on [*stackoverflow.com*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742271/how-to-fix-permission-denied-to-access-property-document). Someone suggested me to post it here...

While trying to automate testing with selenium rc I ran into this problem. I was just following the steps in the tutorials. Here is the code (same as tutorials):

```
[TestFixture]
public class SeleniumTest
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, @"*custom D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 4\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheGoogleTest()
    {
        selenium.Open("/");
        selenium.Type("lst-ib", "selenium");
        try
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsTextPresent("Selenium - Web Browser Automation"));
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test, my firefox-5 browser pops up and the url looks like this:
*http://www.google.com/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=507c2d6ec7214587984f0f86148e9ff5&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&debugMode=false*

I thought the url should be *http://localhost:4444* and changed the url (leaving the rest). Now a selenium page(*RemoteRunner.html* ) opens up (with commands on the right). It then opens the google page, but nothing after that. And *nunit* shows me the test case failed, stating the reason: *Permission denied to access property 'document'*

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm curious: you say firefox-5 pops up, but your file path appears to point to firefox-4 - typo, or something more?

Comment: it is not typo. I had ff4, and I upgraded it from ff menu. It shows me ff5, but the installed folder name is ff4, :)

Comment: It seems that there's a bug in recent Selenium's FirefoxDriver - 2.52.0 shows this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you instantiate you selenium object as ?

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Here *chrome refers to firefox browser and has elevated security privileges on java script security restrictions.

Comment: wow! I tried with "*chrome D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 4\firefox.exe" and seems it is working. Great! My searching, trial and error works of 2 days comes to end. many many thanks!

Comment: :) glad it helped